# How to Convert String to Object in Spring MVC

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson, gson, converters

I need to submit two forms with one submit button, so i did JS function :

```
var submitAllForms = function(){
    var paymentForm = $("#paymentsDetailsForm").serialize();
    var orderForm = $("#orderForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
          method: "post",
          url: "/order",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { paymentsDetailsForm : JSON.stringify(paymentForm), orderForm : JSON.stringify(orderForm) },
          success: alert('form has been sent')
        });
}
```

There are my forms:

```
@Data
public class PaymentDetailsForm  implements Serializable {

    private Date storageDate;
    private String paymentMethod;
    ...
}

@Data
public class OrderForm implements Serializable {

    private String company;
    private String sizeOfMove;
    ... 
}
```

There is my controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/order", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView handleOrder(String paymentsDetailsForm, String orderForm) {
        // How to cast paymentsDetailsForm to PaymentsDetailsForm
        // How to cast orderFormto OrderForm
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("paymentsDetailsForm", new PaymentDetailsForm());

        model.setViewName("/order");
        return model;
    }

}
```

So in the controller, parameter "orderForm" looks like: "company=ROYAL_MOVING&sizeOfMove=STUDIO..."

How can i convert string parameters to OrderForm and PaymentsDetailsForm? Or this issue(submit and handle multiple forms in one method) may be solved some another way?

Answer (score 2):

It's a JSON string, so don't worry. You can search in Google, as there are many ways available to deserialize a JSON string into an object.

One more way is that the first split string from & sign and then again split each group from = sign and now you can map that values with your object in a loop.